# Validating user entered time on Google-Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following variable assignment

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e.range.getColumn() == 3){
      var isValid = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(e.value);
   }
}
```

I am trying to test whether when a person edits a value in the third column of a Google Spreadsheet, whether the value they enter is a valid time in HH:MM format with either a AM or a PM.

I found the above on the internet, but I have never seen this way of understanding time before. Can someone either explain me what is going on, or link me to an article about how the above syntax works?

The hope is to eventually be able to do something like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
    if (the user edits manually edits a value in the third column){
       determine whether the value they entered is a valid time 
       if it is{
          let the change go through
       }
       if it is not{
           alert("Sorry your change can't go through");
       }
    }

}
```

From what I read the alert is already in the correct syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have found is called a "Regular Expression" (RegEx or RegExp), it's a syntax for matching strings which is extremely powerful and can be quite complex. There are lengthy books dedicated entirely to RegEx, so I will try to give you a brief overview of how this one works without getting bogged down in the many specific details that it would take to really explain it fully.

See the RegEx wikipedia here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

See docs on using Regular Expressions in javascript here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

To Be clear, in your example the RegEx part is the statement:

```
/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/
```

A quick summary of how this works is as follows:

- The slashes (/) indicate the start end end of the Regular Expression
- ^ matches the start of the string
- $ matches the end of the string
- ? means "optionally match" the group or character immediately before it
- | means "or"
- the braces ( ) are used for grouping set of matches together
- [] indicate sets of characters to be matched. [0-9]
  will match any number from 0 through 9.
- : is a literal character, it matches the : in the middle of a valid time.

So:

`^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):` says from the start of the string up to the first colon, match 0 through 19 OR 20 to 24  - representing the hours. The question mark after the first [0-1] makes it optional, so you can match 2am as 2:00 or as 02:00

`([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$` says match the minutes (00 to 59) and optionally match the seconds (: plus 00 to 59), up to the end of the string.

Including the ^ and $ special characters ensures that no extra characters are in the string.

A final note of caution, because the RegEx syntax can be quite complex and challenging to read, it's important to not blindly trust RegEx's you find online to do anything important. There are many bad or poorly constructed RegEx's out there for things like validation.  Generally if you come across a RegEx you can't understand, and you can't figure out how it works, it's best to find another solution you do understand.